# Fit view to ImageStatic size

Tags: openlayers, layers, image, sql-view

In OpenLayer 5, i've a long rectangular SVG image (like 7000x600 px) as main layer. I need to limit the view and pan only to its bounds. I tried the code below, but when zooming the layer can't panned anymore and get cropped.

In other words, how can i limit the view to image size and zoom and pan only inside it?

```
var extent = [
    -svgImageSize.width,
    -svgImageSize.height,
    svgImageSize.width,
    svgImageSize.height
]

var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'static-image',
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: extent
});

map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
            url: svgUrl,
            imageExtent: extent,
            projection: projection
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
            projection: projection,
            center: [0, 0],  
            extent: extent,
            maxZoom: 5
        })
});
```

[image]

Comment: In OpenLayers 3 to 5 the view "extent" is a center constraint, not an extent constraint.  For a workaround see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912890/make-boundary-for-ol-static-image/53915534#53915534  Alternatively you could use version 6 (still in beta) where `extent` is an extent constraint unless `constrainOnlyCenter` is specified https://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html

Comment: What mean "is a center constraint, not an extent constraint" ? Anyway, applying the workaround is still possible to pan outside the bounds of image. How to limit the pan only to bounds at every zoom level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the version 5 API:

> **extent** The extent that constrains the **center**, in other words, **center cannot be set outside this extent**.

In the version 6 API:

> **extent** The extent that constrains the **view**, in other words, **nothing outside of this extent can be visible on the map**.

Also your extent is twice the width and height of your image, but it should be the sane size

either user

```
var extent = [
    0,
    0,
    svgImageSize.width,
    svgImageSize.height
]
```

and center at `[ svgImageSize.width/2, svgImageSize.height/2 ]`

or

```
var extent = [
    -svgImageSize.width/2,
    -svgImageSize.height/2,
    svgImageSize.width/2,
    svgImageSize.height/2
]
```

and center at `[ 0, 0 ]`